# How to count uppercase letter in each word in a 2D string

Tags: c, string

I was trying to find out uppercase letters in each word in 2D string using C. But I'm not figuring out with the logic. I was assuming this result -

**Sample Input**

```
2
Dhaka
apple
```

**Sample Output**

```
1
0
```

Here's my code -

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    int count = 0, num;
    char str[50][50];

    printf("How many word you want to enter: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    printf("\nEnter any word: ");

    for(int i=0; i<num; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<num; j++)
        {
            gets(str);
        }
    }

    for(int i=0; str[i]!='\0'; i++)
    {
        for(int j=i+1; j<num; j++)
        {
            if(str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'Z')
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("\n%d\n", count);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The indexing is all messed up. You're allocating a 2D array of 50 strings, of 50 chars each, but you only index into 1D of the array and read the user input into the same place, overwriting the data. The counting indexing is also wrong; you need to consider `str[i][j]`. Try simplifying it by just doing one string at a time and loop around the outside, reading the word and counting letters.

Comment: Mind your compiler warnings. It should complain about using a `char(*)[50]` when a `char*` is expected. Oh! and avoid `gets()` because it's no longer part of Standard C (it's impossible to use it safely).

Answer (score 0):

### Source :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>

int main(){
    int count = 0, num;
    //Enter how many lines you want to enter
    printf("How many lines you want to enter: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    char str[num][100];

    //printf("\nEnter any word: ");

    for(int i=0; i<num; i++){
        //flushs the previous buffer
        getchar();
        //Press enter to enter a line
        scanf("%[^\n]",str[i]);
    }

    for(int i=0;i<num; i++,count=0){
        for(int j=0; str[i][j]!='\0'; j++){
            //printf("%c",str[i][j]);

            //if(str[i][j] >= 'A' && str[i][j] <= 'Z'){
            //  count++;
            //}
            if( isupper(str[i][j]) )
                count++;
        }
        printf("\n%d\n",count);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

### Output :

```
$ gcc string.c && ./a.out
How many lines you want to enter: 3
djjdjd JJ
j3j3j3j JJJJJKK
$#jjd

2

7

0
```

Comment: consider using `isupper()` from `ctype.h`

Comment: Your use of scanf() is no better than OP’s use of gets().